# C++ Enum: Get and return string value by index value

Tags: c++, enums

In C# when requiring to get the textual value of an enum by the index value we can do:

```
String i = ((Enum_Type)index)).ToString();
```

However, it seems that such value cannot be accessed in c++ as conveniently as this. I've tried `(Enum_Type)index` but it seems that it still return a numeric value. I know that the best alternative to enums would be always data model class, however, I'm curious how this can be done in C++, as I'm from a C# background C++ is a lower lever language and little abstract to me.

** Update: Why requiring enum at all?

I have a text file with a series of numeric values that I only wanna be known to the developer, so by reading them and casting them to integers I wanna get the actual value out of the enum.

Comment: To my knowledge it is impossible to retrieve any C++ identifiers at runtime. You'll have to create some accompanying data structure to store the names.